# django admin custom list view

Tags: python, django, admin

I want to customize django admin.. For additing I did this :

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Customized admin template and corresponding 
    views for adding media.
    """


    add_form_template = "admin/add.html"
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if request.method == "POST":
        
            //YOur logic
            
        return super(SomeAdmin,self).add_view(request)
```

Its working fine.. In the same way how can I get custom list view and custom change view ?

Any help ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ModelAdmin` has both the [`change_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view) and [`changelist_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view) methods so you can override them the same way.

Comment: I should declare the template outside the view like list_template = admin/list.html or I can even declare inside ?

Comment: You should do it outside of the view like in your question.  Attribute names are `change_form_template` and `change_list_template`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_form_template

Comment: @catavaran both link are dead.. can you update it ????

Comment: @DevangHingu https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_form_template